# Deep learning model for set of sequences or multiple sequences?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, transformers, attention

My problem is this: I have a **set of sequences as input for the model**, each sequence contains vectors of length *n* (constant length for all sequences). Different sequences can have different lengths.

Can anyone please suggest any paper or blog that describes model appropriate for processing this kind of data? My guess is that it could be something like a combination of RNN (for processing each sequence) and attention mechanism for processing all together.

**More info**: set of sequences is just one input for the model, not the whole dataset. Also, in this problem formulation there is no order between different sequences in one input, therefore they are a set of sequences not a sequence of sequences. The output of the model is not really important, it could be anything, any kind of prediction, I am just interested how to process this kind of data.

Suggestions for models that process sequence of sequences (not just one sequence at a time as input for the model, but multiple sequences) are also welcome :).

Many thanks!